# Rewrite subdomain url to root domain url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I use the following rules to rewrite a subdomain call to a page in the root of the website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_.-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule .? headlines.php?url=%1 [L,QSA]
```

This works fine. I use this for a rss - news related website. For example: http://economy.headlines.com will internally look at http://www.headlines.com/headlines.php?url=economy

I also want to link to the news items in the following way:
economy.headlines.com/news/title/id

How do i do this ? Because every time the first rules are "fired". Even if i make other rules with the [L] flag the other rules are fired and nothing happened.

How can i combine the rules above with new rules which also look at files in the root of the site but with parameters in the url ?

Comment: How are the id and title specified in the incoming request?

Comment: Like /news/name-of-title/12, do you mean this or not? I have tried several things to handle this with rules but i can't come to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to combine both if you evaluate the path component of the request you rewrite:

```
Rewriteengine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_.-]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ headlines.php?url=%1&category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Probably you have to do some fine tuning, but I think you get the idea: the first argument of the `RewriteRule` is a regular expression that splits the request path into its components. Those can be referred to using the `$1` and `$2` notation you can see towards the end of the rule.

---

Edit: added the category parameter to the RewriteRule as discussed in the comments below.

Comment: Maybe i should post the live url's so you can check see: http://voetbal.nieuwsbreakdev.nl/ and http://voetbal.nieuwsbreakdev.nl/voetbal-nieuws/test/1, the last url give the same result as of other rules are not fired.

Comment: OK, that is different to what you posted above... is that `voetbal-nieuws` a fixed string or something dynamic that has to be considered here?

Comment: oh sorry for misunderstanding. voetbal-nieuws is dynamic (for google) can also be economy-nieuws and blabla-nieuws. Thanks for your help in regard

Comment: So what tokens do we have? /???/title/id, so what is the ??? here? How should be be handed over?

Comment: The ??? is category name with the word news (in dutch 'nieuws') in the url to tell google which kind of news it is. /economy-nieuws/title/1

Comment: You did not answer my question how that token should be handed over. So I had to _guess_. I made a modification to the code posted above, have a try with that... Also I do not understand what google has to do with all this.

Comment: You are the best :-) i had to tweak it a little bit to fit the situation but you puth me on the right path. Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. May I suggest that we add the final solution to the answer? That is always good for others reading this post afterwards...

Comment: Your answer was the solution. What i had to tweak was in my code because i was not completely clear to you what i wanted. The call to the subdomain needed to go the headlines.php and the call to the news item to another page. I combined your solution with the first part of code and had to change the line: RewriteRule .? headlines.php?url=%1 [L,QSA] to RewriteRule ^$ headlines.php?url=%1 [L,QSA]